# Windows cachedlogonscount is set to 10, is this per user, or user+computer

Tags: windows, login, user-accounts

We have an XP machine with a cachedlogonscount set to 10. If I connect to that server ( let's say file share ) with user A from computer A, AND I connect with user A from computer B. Does that count as ONE cached log on credential, or two?

Thanks

Comment: You're doing three things wrong: 1. Using Windows XP.  2. Using a desktop as a server. 3. Confusing cached logons with network connection limit.

Answer (score 2):

It counts as one.

The larger issue is that you still have Windows XP deployed in your environment. It has been end-of-support for almost three years now. It's far past due to update to a modern operating system.

---

Edit: per your comments, you aren't actually looking for information about cached logons. You're really trying to figure out why only 10 users can connect to your file share on Windows XP. The answer is that this is a limitation of client OS SKUs and you should be using a server OS instead.

Comment: Hmm, after doing a little more research, I don't think what you are writing is true. Having had a look at 'session manager', it creates a new session per connecting machine. When it gets to the maximum of 10, and I connect with another machine, it kicks off one of the existing ones.

Comment: @user3585420: You're referring to two different things. CachedLogonsCount and the inbound connections limit are not the same thing. It looks like your concern is with the inbound connections limit. Can you confirm that?

Comment: I think you are right, I am confusing the two, this problem seems to be specific to shared folders, so I guess this would be the inbound connections limit? Is this also 10?

Comment: If you are using a client (XP) as a file server, it can only host 10 concurrent connections. You cannot change this. The value is not configurable. You should use a proper server OS instead which does not have this limit.